# Fetching keyword from URL into specific titles on HTML page

Tags: html

I have a HTML page. I want that specific titles will be replaced by the keyword which referred the visitor into the website.
For example, if the link that my visitor clicked on is:

> [www.google.com/?utm_source=dogs]

Than I want a few (H2/H1) titles to be replaced with "dog".

What variable do I need to enter for it to fetch the right keyword?
Is it complicated?

Thanks!

Comment: HTML on its own can’t “fetch” anything. You will need to either use a server-side technology, or client-side JavaScript. Whichever you choose, "query string parameter"/"GET parameter" are probably the first keywords you want to look into, resp. how to access them using your technology of choice.

Comment: HTML is not a programming language. It has no concept of "variables".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP you can get it by just using $_GET variable in your example $_GET['utm_source']. Using javascript you can get the parameters in the url in

```
window.location.search
```

The string you'll get back seem will seems like "?utm_source=dogs&utm_dogs=cats"
what you'll have to do is a set of split to get for each key it's value

what langage are you using ?